# What is meant by this cast? (int (*)[10])

Tags: c, casting

I stumbled across the following cast:

```
(int (*)[10])
```

In my opinion, this is a "pointer to pointer to int".
Let's assume the following array declaration:

```
int array[10];
```

Then I would assume that 
`&array` is of type `(int (*)[10])`

Is this correct?

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) ftw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my opinion, this is a "pointer to pointer to int".

No. Its *pointer to an array of 10 `int`s*.

> Then I would assume that  `&array` is of type `(int (*)[10])`

Yes. Your assumption is correct. `&array` is the address of array `array` and is of type `int (*)[10]`.

Answer (score 6):

It is a pointer to an integer array of size 10 and not a *'pointer to a pointer of int'*.

For example when you pass the type

```
 char arr[20][10]
```

to a function it decays to type char(*)[10]

As the compiler has to know the no of columns to effectively convert a 2d array to linear allocation in memory it is not the same as type int **.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an educational example which is aligned to your observations (*compiled with no warnings*):

```
int array[10]; /* an array of 10 ints */
int (*ptr)[10] = &array; /* a pointer to an array of 10 ints */

/* a function which receives a pointer to an array of 10 ints as param */
int myfunc (int (*param)[10])
{
    return 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* a pointer to a function that accepts a pointer to an array of 10 ints as parameter and returns an int */
    int (*func)(int (*)[10]);

    func = myfunc; /* no cast needed. The objects are of the same type */
    /* func = (int (*)(int (*)[10])) myfunc; */ /* with cast */

    (*func)(ptr);  /* function pointer called with ptr parameter */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a pointer to an array of 10 integers.